# Install vim plugin python-syntax on macOS without third party package manager

Tags: macos, vim, python

I would like to install the [vim package python-syntax](https://github.com/vim-python/python-syntax).  The README says to use a package manager but it must be possible using vim's builtin package capability.  I cloned the package using

```
git clone https://github.com/vim-python/python-syntax ~/.vim/pack/syntax/start
```

There is a directory `syntax` inside `start` which contains `python.vim` which has the syntax information.  I see that directory listed when I enter `:set runtimepath`.  Now according to my understanding of the vim help (`:help packages`) vim should automatically load this package.  But when I enter `:help local-additions` I do not see `python-syntax` listed.  More to the point, the syntax highlighting is not there when I use vim to open a .py file.

Comment: Did you restart Vim? Have you done ":syntax on"?

Comment: Yes I have restarted vim and I have `syntax on` in my .vimrc.

Comment: Does the script show up in the output of `:scriptnames`?

Comment: The script does not show up in the output of `:scriptnames`.

Comment: Then you have a misconfiguration somewhere. Perhaps try `filetype plugin on` as well?

Comment: Adding `filetype plugin on` to .vimrc made no difference.